# Changing discord.py bot using command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I go about changing my bots avatar with a command such as `pfpchange` or something similar?
Any help would be appreciated, I've tried the following code with zero luck.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=')
client.remove_command('help')
pfp = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/751402019046162494/774903321844645968/pinkbulba.jpg'

@client.command()
async def pfpchange(ctx):
    await client.edit_profile(password=None, avatar=pfp)

client.run('super secret token')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bot.edit_profile()` was renamed to `ClientUser.edit()`, which is why it doesn't work. You're supposed to use `Bot.user.edit()`.

More info in the relevant [API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=edit_profile)